# What's the meaning of verifier is "ppt" ? and why we need verifier is ppt in Interactive Proof?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, security-definition, verifiability

I have been studying Zero Knowledge Proof. I found the Definition of Interactive Proof says that Verifier is ppt.
And I only found in [PP (Complexity) Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PP_(complexity)) says that **ppt**:

> Turing machines that are polynomially-bound and probabilistic are
> characterized as **PPT**, which stands for probabilistic polynomial-time
> machines.[2] This characterization of Turing machines does not require
> a bounded error probability. Hence, PP is the complexity class
> containing all problems solvable by a **PPT** machine with an error
> probability of less than 1/2.

Still very confusing about the PPT, what's the full name of PPT?
we do we need the verifier to be PPT for interactive Proof?

[image]

Resource from: [Zero Knowledge Proofs  CS276: Cryptography, UC Berkeley](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ealexch/docs/CS276-F2015/lecture-19.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PPT is Probabilistic Polynomial Time Algorithm.

A deterministic verifier will always produce the same output/reply for any input.

Let's take an interactive sequence.

Prover sends $p_1$.

Verifier replies with $f(p_1) = v_1$

Prover replies back with $g(v_1) = p_2$

The function $f$ which the verifier uses is deterministic. i.e. for a particular input, it always replies with the same reply.

In a probabilistic verifier, $f$ also has randomisation as input. i.e. $g$ takes 2 inputs $f(v_i, r)$ where $r$ is a random value. Hence $f$ is not deterministic, and the verifier is a probabilistic verifier. And if $f$ runs in polynomial time, the verifier is a Probabilistic Polynomial Time (PPT) verifier.